# Horizontal Scrolling issue on Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, scroll, codepen

After following an example on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/lemmin/pen/xRyXMZ), I discovered that it did not work correctly on Firefox. I thought it was just a missing pre-fix, but this did not work.

It works slightly when you slide horizontally on your mouse or trackpad, but this is not satisfactory.

Try to click on the scroll area, it will not scroll completely to the next section unlike on Chrome.

It does not scroll to the next section via the scroll wheel. When used on a Mac with a magic mouse it works intermittently, but the user has to swipe their finger to across rather than up and down.

How can I solve this?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Georgia;
}

#container .box {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

#container .box>div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 96px;
  color: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;
  line-height: .7;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#container {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);
  transform-origin: top left;
  background-color: #999;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vw;
}

#container2 {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100vh);
  transform-origin: top left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 0;
}

.one {
  background-color: #45CCFF;
}

.two {
  background-color: #49E83E;
}

.three {
  background-color: #EDDE05;
}

.four {
  background-color: #E84B30;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="container2">
    <div class="box one">
      <div>1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box two">
      <div>2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box three">
      <div>3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box four">
      <div>Last</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the example [codepen](https://codepen.io/lemmin/pen/xRyXMZ)

Comment: What specifically is the problem?

Comment: @showdev try to click on the scroll area, it will not scroll completely to the next section unlike on chrome

Comment: @showdev, Yes it does not scroll to the next section via the scroll wheel.  When used on a Mac with a magic mouse it works intermittently, but the user has to swipe their finger to across rather than up and down.